# Sending a response after jobs have finished processing in Express

Tags: node.js, express

So, I have Express server that accepts a request. The request is web scraping that takes 3-4 minute to finish. I'm using Bull to queue the jobs and processing it as and when it is ready. The challenge is to send this results from processed jobs back as response. Is there any way I can achieve this? I'm running the app on heroku, but heroku has a request timeout of 30sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to send response immediately due to timeout. Since your process takes about 3-4 minutes, it is better to send a response immediately mentioning that the request was successfully received and will be processed.

Now, when the task is completed, you can use socket.io or web sockets to notify the client from the server side. You can also pass a response.

The client side also can check continuously if the job was completed on the server side, this is called polling and is required with older browsers which don't support web sockets. socket.io falls back to polling when browsers don't support web sockets.

Visit socket.io for more information and documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to do this using socket.io. I was wondering how scalable is socket io when hundreds of users are connected.

Comment: No Problem. socket.io is used in production by many companies. For 100s of users, definitely fine.  But, definitely look for other blogs and articles and explore more.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to wait until the back end finished do the request identified who is requesting . Authenticate the user. Do a `res.status(202).send({message:”text});`
Even though the response was sended to the client you can keep processing and stuff

NOTE: Do not put a return keyword before res.status...

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 202 Accepted response status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not have started yet. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.

202 is non-committal, meaning that there is no way for the HTTP to later send an asynchronous response indicating the outcome of processing the request. It is intended for cases where another process or server handles the request, or for batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to this problem is socket.io library. It can send data to client send whenever you want. It triggers a function on client side which receives the data. Socket.io supports different languages and it is really ease to use.

[website link](https://socket.io/)

[Documentation Link](https://socket.io/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

->Request **time out occurs when your connection is idle**, different servers implement in a different way so *`timeout time differs`*

1)The solution for this timeout problem would be to make your `connections open(constant)`, that is the connection between *client and servers should **`remain constant`***.

2. So for such scenarios `use WebSockets`, which ensures that after the initial request and response handshake between client and server the connection stays open.
3. there are many libraries to implement realtime connection.Eg **Pubnub,socket.io**. **This is the same technology used for live streaming.**
4. Node js can handle many concurrent connections and its lightweight too, won't use many resources too.

Answer (score 0):

- create a jobs table in a database or persistant storage like redis
- save each job in the table upon request with a unique id
- update status to `running` on starting the job
- sent HTTP 202 - Accepted
- At the client implement a polling script, At the server implement a job status route/api. The api accept a job id and queries the job table and respond with the status
- When the job is finished update the job table with status `completed`, when the jon is errored updated the job table with status `failed` and maybe a description column to store the cause for error

This solution makes your system horizontaly scalable and distributed. It also prevents the consequences of unexpected connection drops. Polling interval depends on average job completion duration. I would recommend an average interval of 5 second
This can be even improved to store job completion progress in the jobs table so that the client can even display a progress bar